# Is an off-canvas menu with JavaScript toggle a good practice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, getuikit

For my web-page I'm looking into implementing an off-canvas menu for small screen sizes. The frontend framework I'm using (UIKit) implements the toggling using JavaScript.

Is this considered good practice? Or should I rather look into a solution solely based on CSS? I have no idea how many people will have JavaScript disabled on their mobile devices (which is the use case for the off-canvas menu, it is not shown on larger screen sizes via CSS media queries) and thus could not toggle the menu.

Comment: Extremely hard to surf the web these days with script disabled. Can add a [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag if it makes you feel more comfortable

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and (I have) implement it and have a fallback. I've seen it done many times. There are plenty of examples of its usage, so I'd go ahead with your plan to implement it.

Comment: How does your fallback look like?

Comment: I took my fallback from this demo. [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms)